# Run javascript function (execCommand('SaveAs'..) on an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, iframe

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){

        $('#myiframe')[0].document.execCommand('SaveAs',false,'somexml.xml');

    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="myiframe" src="somexml.xml" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I know that `execCommand` only works in IE, but i cant get this to work. All I want is a "save as" dialog, with the iframe content beeing saved. So I want to run the function in the iframe, not on the "main" page.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var oIframe = $('#myiframe')[0];
var oDoc = oIframe.contentWindow || oIframe.contentDocument;
if (oDoc.document) {
    oDoc = oDoc.document;
}
oDoc.execCommand('SaveAs',false,'somexml.xml'); // this line will work only in IE
```

See this link for getting the document object of an iframe correctly: http://xkr.us/articles/dom/iframe-document/

Comment: The vars in the document object getting code is something i got from the site pointed out! :-) But hungarian notation is not all that bad (especially so, if you'll be obfuscating anyway)

Comment: Thanks, but when i open the saved file all i see is `<HTML></HTML>` instead of the xml tags that ive hoped for :(

Comment: Well, that i believe has something to do with the execCommand call. You might want to ensure that you are invoking it on the correct document object. Also with IE, anything can happen! ;-)

Comment: Well, i know the iframe is targeted the correct way. Maybe it isnt possible to generate popups and such from within an iframe?

Comment: That is a possibility. In IE we cannot (at least by normal route) check out an iframe source etc, like we can in FF, Chrome etc.. Probably stems from this core limitation of some sort.